# How to pass object from one component from other component using angular6

Tags: angular6

I am new to angular. I am creating form, and after submitting form, I will get data in object. I need to pass that object to the other component, is it possible by using @Input property. If Yes how can we achieve that by using @Input property. Please help me.

parent.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      Name: <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name"><br/>
     Fname: <input type="text" formControlName="fname" placeholder="FirstNAme"><br/>
     Lname: <input type="text" formControlName="lname" placeholder="LastName"><br/>
    <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

<h1>Hello {{message}}</h1> <br/> 

  <app-forms [parentObject]="FormObject">]</app-forms>
```

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup ,FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form1',
  templateUrl: './form1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form1.component.css']
})
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {

  addForm:FormGroup;

  parentObject:Object;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.addForm=this.fb.group({
  name:[''],
  fname:[''],
  lname:['']

})
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.addForm.value);
    var  FormObject=this.addForm.value
  }

}
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentObject: Object;
 constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.parentObject);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your child component define input as:

```
import { Input} from '@angular/core';

 @Input() some_variable_name: Object;
```

now in your parent component pass your object as:

```
<child-component [some_variable_name] = "object_variable" />
```

check the official documentation for more details: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I am getting object as undefined in child component. I have updated my code. Please check my code.

Comment: you have defined `FormObject` locally inside `onSubmit` function. define it globally like with `parentObject`. also you don't need to define `parentObject`  in parent component.